# How to automatically re-run failed test cases using TestNG

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

I tried with Retry Listener, but after the failed test case execution, rest all the test cases are executing twice(with maxRetryCount=1)
Please suggest me any solution

Comment: If you organize and execute tests using xml make sure you add the retry listener there 
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="utils.Listeners.Retry"/>
        <listener class-name="utils.OtherListener"/>
    </listeners>
and also when I implemented the retry mechanism I set the Retry class to extend the base test class (where I initialize the drivez and set the driver capabilities) from listener like this:
public class Retry extends BaseTest implements IRetryAnalyzer , ITestListener {...}

Comment: Yes I have added retry listener in xml file. What is the content of OtherListener class? Also I have tried extends base class, Still the same problem persists. In my project, in one test data file I have 5 to 10 test cases.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.